# Message: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php

Me tiene bastante cansado ya por no decir otra cosa.

Integre por composer ImageManager.

Agregue la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
```

Intento cargar al sistema una foto y me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo bastante, ya descomente del archivo php.ini la linea:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Tambien cambie el donmbre por solamente gd2 o gd y tampoco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Consulta desde la linea de comandos php -v para conocer tu version de php y puedas ver que alternativas tienes para instalar la libreria gd2.

Comment: ahi edite la publicacion

Comment: Gracias master, lo pude solucionar